# I have to print the position of an alphabet in c language

Tags: c

Basically, if the input is `"1"` I need it to say `a`
if the input is `"2"` it needs to say `b` and so on and so forth.

I have tried `if else` trees and they are L O N G so please help me.

Comment: In ASCII letters are sequential, so `'a' + 1 == 'b'` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a list of chars storing the alphabet and just index out the values

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number;
    char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("%c",alpha[number-1]);// because when indexing, the first "spot" is 0 but you want 1 to return a not so the -1 readjust that

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to get the opposite of it as well? like i enter a alphabet and it gives me the number?

Comment: @FerrariNevada with the answers and comments posted, you should be able to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

another solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("%c",'a'+number-1);

    return 0;
}
```